Can't cross-compile simple code with boost/asio/ssl.hpp for AIX
When I cross compile a simple program including boost/asio/ssl.hpp, the linker gives a lot of undefined reference errors
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

/opt/crossaix/bin/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0-g++ -L/tmp/vcpkg/lib/ -I/tmp/vcpkg/include/ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o custmain -lpthread -lcrypto -latomic

/tmp/vcpkg/lib and /tmp/vcpkg/include contain libcrypto.a (from openssl) and boost::asio and openssl headers. This was obtained from vcpkg.
The errors and warnings:
In file included from /tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:757:0,
                 from /tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:18,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp: In destructor 'boost::asio::ssl::context::rsa_cleanup::~rsa_cleanup()':
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:54:29: warning: 'void RSA_free(RSA*)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/rsa.h:299): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   ~rsa_cleanup() { if (p) ::RSA_free(p); }
                             ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:54:39: warning: 'void RSA_free(RSA*)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/rsa.h:299): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   ~rsa_cleanup() { if (p) ::RSA_free(p); }
                                       ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp: In destructor 'boost::asio::ssl::context::dh_cleanup::~dh_cleanup()':
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:60:28: warning: 'void DH_free(DH*)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/dh.h:207): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   ~dh_cleanup() { if (p) ::DH_free(p); }
                            ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:60:37: warning: 'void DH_free(DH*)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/dh.h:207): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   ~dh_cleanup() { if (p) ::DH_free(p); }
                                     ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp: In member function 'boost::system::error_code boost::asio::ssl::context::use_rsa_private_key(const boost::asio::const_buffer&, boost::asio::ssl::context_base::file_format, boost::system::error_code&)':
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:936:29: warning: 'RSA* d2i_RSAPrivateKey_bio(BIO*, RSA**)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/x509.h:619): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       rsa_private_key.p = ::d2i_RSAPrivateKey_bio(bio.p, 0);
                             ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:936:59: warning: 'RSA* d2i_RSAPrivateKey_bio(BIO*, RSA**)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/x509.h:619): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       rsa_private_key.p = ::d2i_RSAPrivateKey_bio(bio.p, 0);
                                                           ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:939:29: warning: 'RSA* PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(BIO*, RSA**, int (*)(char*, int, int, void*), void*)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/pem.h:450): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       rsa_private_key.p = ::PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(
                             ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:941:22: warning: 'RSA* PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(BIO*, RSA**, int (*)(char*, int, int, void*), void*)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/pem.h:450): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
           cb_userdata);
                      ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:952:13: warning: 'int SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey(SSL_CTX*, RSA*)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/ssl.h:1813): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       if (::SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey(handle_, rsa_private_key.p) == 1)
             ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:952:65: warning: 'int SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey(SSL_CTX*, RSA*)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/ssl.h:1813): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       if (::SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey(handle_, rsa_private_key.p) == 1)
                                                                 ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp: In member function 'boost::system::error_code boost::asio::ssl::context::use_rsa_private_key_file(const string&, boost::asio::ssl::context_base::file_format, boost::system::error_code&)':
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:1030:9: warning: 'int SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey_file(SSL_CTX*, const char*, int)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/ssl.h:1700): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   if (::SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey_file(
         ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:1031:45: warning: 'int SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey_file(SSL_CTX*, const char*, int)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/ssl.h:1700): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         handle_, filename.c_str(), file_type) != 1)
                                             ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp: In member function 'boost::system::error_code boost::asio::ssl::context::do_use_tmp_dh(BIO*, boost::system::error_code&)':
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:1096:23: warning: 'DH* PEM_read_bio_DHparams(BIO*, DH**, int (*)(char*, int, int, void*), void*)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/pem.h:472): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   dh_cleanup dh = { ::PEM_read_bio_DHparams(bio, 0, 0, 0) };
                       ^
/tmp/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:1096:57: warning: 'DH* PEM_read_bio_DHparams(BIO*, DH**, int (*)(char*, int, int, void*), void*)' is deprecated (declared at /tmp/include/openssl/pem.h:472): Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   dh_cleanup dh = { ::PEM_read_bio_DHparams(bio, 0, 0, 0) };
                                                         ^
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x3ee): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x4ee): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x1b22): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x1b26): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x1bb2): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x1d7e): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x2b1a): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x2e8a): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x2f2a): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x2f52): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x2f72): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x3a06): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.pr+0x3a0a): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.tc+0x0): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-e_aes.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/evp/e_aes.c:(.tc+0x0): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-gcm128.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/modes/gcm128.c:(.pr+0x1cb6): undefined reference to `gcm_init_p8'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-gcm128.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/modes/gcm128.c:(.pr+0x1cba): undefined reference to `gcm_gmult_p8'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-gcm128.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/modes/gcm128.c:(.pr+0x1cbe): undefined reference to `gcm_ghash_p8'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-gcm128.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/modes/gcm128.c:(.pr+0x53d2): undefined reference to `gcm_init_p8'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-gcm128.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/modes/gcm128.c:(.pr+0x53d6): undefined reference to `gcm_gmult_p8'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-gcm128.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/modes/gcm128.c:(.pr+0x53da): undefined reference to `gcm_ghash_p8'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-gcm128.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/modes/gcm128.c:(.tc+0x0): undefined reference to `gcm_init_p8'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-gcm128.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/modes/gcm128.c:(.tc+0x0): undefined reference to `gcm_gmult_p8'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-gcm128.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/modes/gcm128.c:(.tc+0x0): undefined reference to `gcm_ghash_p8'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_ccm_hw.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_ccm_hw.c:(.pr+0x5e): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_gcm_hw.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_gcm_hw.c:(.pr+0x56): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_hw.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_hw.c:(.pr+0x10e): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_hw.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_hw.c:(.pr+0x25e): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_ocb_hw.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_ocb_hw.c:(.pr+0x8a): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_ocb_hw.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_ocb_hw.c:(.pr+0x8e): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_wrp.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_wrp.c:(.pr+0x1626): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_wrp.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_wrp.c:(.pr+0x16fa): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_wrp.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_wrp.c:(.pr+0x18b6): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_wrp.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_wrp.c:(.pr+0x198a): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_xts_hw.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_xts_hw.c:(.pr+0x21e): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_xts_hw.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_xts_hw.c:(.pr+0x222): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libdefault-lib-cipher_aes_xts_hw.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/providers/implementations/ciphers/cipher_aes_xts_hw.c:(.pr+0x2fa): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-aes_cbc.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/aes/aes_cbc.c:(.pr+0x16): undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
/tmp/lib//libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-aes_cbc.o):../src/nssl-3.1.4-c7b0e04810.clean/crypto/aes/aes_cbc.c:(.pr+0x32): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

For example, the linker says it doesn't find AES_encrypt, but this function should be in /tmp/vcpkg/libcrypto.a
I copied /tmp/vcpkg/libcrypto.a to the AIX machine and checked it with nm, and it seems AES_encrypt is in /tmp/vcpkg/libcrypto.a
-bash-5.1# nm libcrypto.a | grep AES_encrypt
.AES_encrypt         T        4736
AES_encrypt          U           -
AES_encrypt          d         128           4
AES_encrypt          U           -
AES_encrypt          d         240           4
.AES_encrypt         U           -
.AES_encrypt         U           -
AES_encrypt          U           -
AES_encrypt          d          80           4
AES_encrypt          U           -
AES_encrypt          d         160           4
AES_encrypt          U           -
AES_encrypt          d       17164           4
AES_encrypt          U           -
AES_encrypt          d         492           4
AES_encrypt          U           -
AES_encrypt          d         704           4
AES_encrypt          U           -
AES_encrypt          d        1288           4
AES_encrypt          U           -
AES_encrypt          d         628           4
AES_encrypt          U           -
AES_encrypt          d        6908           4
AES_encrypt          U           -
AES_encrypt          d         924           4

I tried adding -lssl but it didn't help

"was obtained from vcpkg" - how, exactly? The nm output shown really doesn't suffice to verify that the objects files are suitable for the target platform. Perhaps you can also include a link to where you get your cross-compilation toolchain

What do you mean by "you copied libcrypto.a to the AIX machine"? Is it even compatible with that machine? Does it get used, or does AIX have a system-provided libcrypto.a that is actually found by the linker?

@ChristianStieber I mean, I cross-compiled /tmp/vcpkg/libcrypto.a on Linux under aix powerpc (host - linux, target - aix-powerpc), and then copied the library on the aix machine to run nm and look at the symbols in this library (I don’t have cross nm, so do it on Linux)
Yes, compatible. /tmp/vcpkg/libcrypto.a was cross-compiled for the aix powerpc platform. Why should it not be compatible? If it were not compatible, nm would show an error

"Perhaps you can also include a link to where you get your cross-compilation toolchain" The cross toolchain was downloaded a long time ago and not by me, so I can’t provide the link        /opt/crossaix/bin/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0-g++ --version
powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0-g++ (GCC) 4.8.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. @sehe

"how, exactly?" In manifest mode. There are files vcpkg-configuration.json, vcpkg.json, ports/, triplets/, which specify which libraries are needed, how to compile them, which toolchain to use, etc. I'll probably try cross-compiling openssl without vcpkg and see if there's a difference. @sehe
